# Ways to compare a set of values against a base value

Tags: statistics

I have a statistics doubt. Consider I have the following values.

```
Base Model      Model 1     Model 2
5               7           4
10              12          8
15              17          12
20              23          21
25              30          27
30              31          31
35              34          37
40              43          43
45              45          44
50              51          50
```

I want a better way to represent Model1 and Model2 by comparing against the Base Model. I used an error metric:

$$\frac{|\text{My_Model} - \text{Base_Model}|}{\text{Base_Model}} \times 100$$

What other methods can I use to represent these. I want to plot these as a graph and see how good Model 1 and Model 2 are w.r.t Base Model. Can I use any form of distributions?

Comment: What is your research question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the chi square goodness of fit test the measure is ∑(observed-expected)$^2/expected. The change to your formula would be to square the numerator and not express it as a percentage.